# preventDefault is not preventing button from calling method in my class file

Tags: jquery

I have a button that preforms a search action on my page.  I'm using jquery to do a simple validation on a zip code for 5 digits.  I'm using preventDefault to stop my button from running the search if the zip code is not valid.  However, the preventDefault method does not seem to be working.  It still runs the search even if the zip code is not validated correctly.

Here is my jquery code:

```
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
        var searchButton = j$('[id$=theFilterButton]');
        var isValid = true;
        searchButton.click(function(e) {
            var zip = j$('[id$="ZipCodeFilter"]').val();
            var reg = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if((zip.length) < 5 || (zip.length) > 5 ) {
                isValid = false;
                console.log("zip code length is not 5");
            }
            if (!reg.test(zip)){
                isValid = false;
                console.log("zip is not digits");
            }
            if(!isValid) {
                console.log("zip is not valid. Stop processing!!!!");
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });     
    });
```

shouldn't the preventDefault method stop the button from calling my code in the class file?

Thanks for any help.
Regards.

Comment: Without seeing your html, have you tried `return false;` instead of `preventDefault`?

Comment: Unrelated, but why not just use `"#theFilterButton"` as the selector?

Comment: I have tried to use return false with the same result.  I'm not using the `#theFilterButton` as the selector because it is VF code within Salesforce and you have to select VF tags using the above method.

Comment: is your button inside a form or something? in that case you should handle the form **submit** event. Please post your html too, is hard to predict what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

It'll only prevent the default action from occurring. If there's an event handler higher up in the DOM tree (say a parent form), that handles submitting the form (and the event bubbles up to that) `preventDefault` will not stop that.

Instead, you'd want to call `stopPropagation` (with or without `preventDefault`, depending on the default action)

`return false` may also be used, when using jQuery (which is similar to calling `preventDefault` with `stopPropagation`).

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`:

http://jsfiddle.net/1jfpkf1n/

The first square, if you click the inner, will throw two alerts (if the inner square was a link - the page would not navigate, but the outer event listener still gets called...)

The second square, when you click the inner box, will alert but then stop the event from bubbling up (thanks to stopPropagation).

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the response.  I tried using a combination of `stopPropagation`, `preventDefault` and `return false` and in the debug I'm getting into the last branch where it checks if the zip is valid. The log shows 'zip is not valid. Stop processing!!!!`.  But, the search still runs.  I'm looking at some code I've done the exact same thing and it works fine.  I'm not sure what I'm missing?